# Is there a OpenCV specific way to find the vertices of a polygon in a binary image and re-generate the image using those vertices

Tags: c++, opencv, polygon, vertices

I want to find the coordinates of the vertices of a polygon in a binary image (Mat). How to do that? I will store those coordinates to represent that image. Actually I will store those coordinates in a database and later I want to use those vertices' coordinates and regenerate the original image. So how to do that too? I can develop a complex algorithm to do these two tasks, but I hope there should be a opencv specific simple approach. Following is a sample image I'm using.

[[image]

There is a similarly looking question asked by me at [Store details of a binary image consisting simple polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646643/store-details-of-a-binary-image-consisting-simple-polygons) , but this question is specifying a very small part of that question. Previous one has a wider scope and questions on the possibility of using object writing approach too and asks about the best practical approach. But this is specific. And previous one is about storing Mat data but this one is on finding the vertices of a polygon. So in this question I want exactly to know how to find the vertices of a polygon, but nothing on storing Mat data.

Comment: What is the meaning of repeating your question twice?? You have already asked your question 3 hours before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646643/store-details-of-a-binary-image-consisting-simple-polygons