# Bringing AI to industrial robotic programming

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, artificial-intelligence

the story is simple, I'll work for an enterprise that make a metal part, they are using **ABB** robots ( that use **ABB** rapid language ) and I'm working mostly in Python for my part, my boss asked me to find a way to speed up the robot programming because it's a pain.
And I'm here to ask advice not a solution.

the actual process is **(" Design > laser cut ( mcode) > grinding ( ABB rapid ) ")**
In my mind the idea would be to use picture recognition of the design (edge detection ) for dataset making ( we have thousands of products for that ) then "**cutting**" this image in part that will create the code needed for robots actions for each part, one in mcode and one in **ABB** rapid both with minimal data to enter by the robot dev.

> my question is, would it be possible from the image recognition edge
>   detection to create a high definition curve and from it to create a
>   matrix, for the next part eventually making another dataset from the
>   past script that will recognize the **"type of point = type of
>   move"**.

is the idea seems correct to you actually?

Comment: You could maybe look at `potrace` to convert an edge-detected image to a sequence of `move from here to here` instructions... https://stackoverflow.com/a/33647709/2836621

Comment: thanks i'll check for that